# Simple Primefaces app with Spring boot

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-boot

Just started working with **Spring Boot** and I'm trying to create a simple application using **Primefaces**, but I can't find a way to show my `.xhtml` views.

When I access to `localhost:8080` I get the *Whitelabel Error Page* with the next error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

I used to have my views on `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/` but I understand that with the use of the `fat jar` for Spring boot apps now I have to place my views on `src/main/resources`, but I'm not sure if I still have to use `ViewResolver`.

**/src/main/java/Application.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    /*@Bean
    public ViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
        return resolver;
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);    
        System.out.println("INITIALIZED");
    }

}
```

**/src/main/java/BaseController.java:**

```
@Controller
public class BaseController{

    private static final String VIEW_INDEX = "index";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(ModelMap model) {
        return VIEW_INDEX;
    }
}
```

**/src/main/resources/views/index.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Application</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <p:spinner></p:spinner>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**/src/main/resources/faces-config.xml:**

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

**Spring-boot log:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2016-11-18 13:16:58.511  INFO 6384 --- [           main] c.crivero.cloudfoundry_test.Application  : Starting Application v0.0.1 on XXX with PID 6384 (C:\Users\criverom\Documents\EclipseWorkspace\cloudfoundry-test\target\cloudfoundry-test-0.0.1.jar started by criverom in C:\Users\criverom\Documents\EclipseWorkspace\cloudfoundry-test)
2016-11-18 13:16:58.550  INFO 6384 --- [           main] c.crivero.cloudfoundry_test.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-11-18 13:16:58.725  INFO 6384 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.Annotat
ionConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1698c449: startup date [Fri Nov 18 13:16:58 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-18 13:17:03.160  INFO 6384 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-11-18 13:17:03.195  INFO 6384 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-11-18 13:17:03.199  INFO 6384 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2016-11-18 13:17:03.414  INFO 6384 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-11-18 13:17:03.415  INFO 6384 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4695 ms
2016-11-18 13:17:03.830  INFO 6384 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-11-18 13:17:03.839  INFO 6384 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-18 13:17:03.840  INFO 6384 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-18 13:17:03.840  INFO 6384 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-18 13:17:03.841  INFO 6384 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-11-18 13:17:04.232  INFO 6384 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1698c449: startup date [Fri Nov 18 13:16:58 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-18 13:17:04.458  INFO 6384 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.crivero.cloudfoundry_test.BaseController.welcome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
2016-11-18 13:17:04.469  INFO 6384 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-11-18 13:17:04.470  INFO 6384 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-11-18 13:17:04.564  INFO 6384 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-18 13:17:04.567  INFO 6384 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-18 13:17:04.641  INFO 6384 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-11-18 13:17:05.060  INFO 6384 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-11-18 13:17:05.197  INFO 6384 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-11-18 13:17:05.209  INFO 6384 --- [           main] c.crivero.cloudfoundry_test.Application  : Started Application in 7.94 seconds (JVM running for 8.895)
INITIALIZED
2016-11-18 13:18:44.775  INFO 6384 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-11-18 13:18:44.775  INFO 6384 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started

2016-11-18 13:18:44.815  INFO 6384 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 39 ms
```

Comment: so it works if you put an `<h:inputText>` in the page instead of a `<p:spinner/>`

Comment: @Kukeltje Nope, same error. It's like the view isn't being mapped correctly.